# jquery - building up an event for a text field "changing"? (keypress works except no backspace event)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a "search" box that is supposed to be able to search data "live". Right now if I attach the "keypress" event to it and update the results, it works pretty good. However, if they press backspace it doesn't account for that (refresh the results).

I understand I can probably account for the "backspace" key.

But am I missing any other possibilities? I want *any* change of the text in the input to be triggering the "event" or calling the refresh function.

The one thing I don't want to do is set "alarms" or "timers" to check every so often if it has changed.

Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To insure that you are triggering your data search after each changing of the text field, you should check if the text field has changed after each `.keyup()` or `.keydown()`

```
// The following only works for keyboard input, to handle mouse copy / paste
// see the example after this
$(function() {                         // <== Doc ready  

    var inputVal = $("input").val();   // a variable to hold the text
                                       // set it up w the initial value then see 
                                       // if the input value changes.

    $("input").keyup(function() {

        // check for change of the text field after each key up
        if(this.value != inputVal)
        {
            // Do your search, etc.
            // ...

            // Reset the temp value for the next comparison
            inputVal = this.value
        }
    });
});
```

[Try it out with this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Upz6/)

To handle mouse copy paste (which Filipe pointed out doesn't work with the above), jQuery has the option of binding multiple events to one element, and it has a `paste` and `cut` event. The problem with these is that they are triggered immediately on paste but BEFORE the input box contents are actually changed, so we need a timeout... in fact a timeout would be a nice feature for the whole thing, so that if the user is typing quickly, then we wait until they are done:

```
$(function() {    // <== Doc ready  

    var inputVal = $("input").val(), // a variable to hold the text
                                     // set it up w the initial value then see 
                                     // if the input value changes.

        timer,
        checkForChange = function() {
            var self = this; // or just use .bind(this)

            // we only want to check on the input after the user has settled down,
            // so use a timeout and clear it if another input comes in
            if (timer) { clearTimeout(timer); }

            // check for change of the text field after each key up
            timer = setTimeout(function() {
                if(self.value != inputVal) {
                    // Do your search, etc.
                    $("span").html(parseInt($("span").html(),10) + 1);

                    // Reset the temp value for the next time
                    inputVal = self.value
                }
            }, 250);
        };

    $("input").bind('keyup paste cut', checkForChange);
});
```

So now we check for the keyboard, for pasting in, and for cutting out.

[Try it out with this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pajtai/Ytwht/)

---

Comment: @FilipeGiusti Added a second snippet that handles `paste` and `cut` ==> http://jsfiddle.net/pajtai/Ytwht/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Common event behaviors](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/common-input-element-attributes.html#common-event-behaviors) (which is about event behaviors that are shared by different kinds of `input` elements in HTML5). In particular, the `change` event is supposed to do what you want. (One of these decades, anyway.) It should, at least, be safe to handle this event, even if many browsers don't yet support it.

Comment: The `change` event is only triggered on blur for text fields, so it wouldn't really work in this case. From http://api.jquery.com/change/ ==> `For select boxes, checkboxes, and radio buttons, the event is fired immediately when the user makes a selection with the mouse, but for the other element types the event is deferred until the element loses focus.`